# Linear Equations - Solution Space and Linear Dependence

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider "any" two systems of  linear equations: Sys_A and Sys_B.

Are the below two statements equivalent?

Statement (1): Sys_A and Sys_B have same solution space

Statement (2): Sys_A and Sys_B are mutually linearly dependent

Statement (2) implies Statement (1) is rather obvious, I'm not sure about the other direction

Thanks

Comment: What does it mean for two linear systems to be linearly dependent?

Comment: That every equation of one system is a linear combination of the equations in the other system. Sorry if that was not made clear, Thanks

Comment: This implies that there is a change of basis that turns one system to the other.

Comment: The same with solution space. Check what happens when the matrix is invertible. Then think what happens when the matrices have the "same" non trivial kernels